# Where can I see the content of Channel.write()

Tags: netty

I'm new to netty and trying the examples they have on their website. I'm doing the HttpFileServer for version 3.9 and and in the Handler class I saw this

```
    Channel ch = e.getChannel();

    // Write the initial line and the header.
    ch.write(response);
```

Where/how can I see what is being written to the a channel instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a LoggingHandler to the ChannelPipeline. This will log out all the data which is received and written.

Comment: Sorry I didn't accept your answer earlier. This was the very first question I had posted and wasn't too familiar with the website. Thanks for the answer